# Problems with Gas Consumption When Deploying a Smart Contract with a Function for Uniswap Liquidity

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, gas

I am encountering an issue when deploying my smart contract on the network. The contract deploys successfully without the inclusion of a function that handles a 2% liquidity tax, which is supposed to be added to the Uniswap liquidity pool. However, when I include this function, I face a problem with high gas requirements, and the contract cannot be deployed. The error message states: "Gas requirement of function is infinite: If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed."

Here are the main points I would like to discuss:

Function Optimization: What are the options for optimizing this function to reduce gas consumption? Is it possible that some operations within the function are too demanding in terms of gas?

Issues with Loops and External Calls: Does this function contain any inefficient loops or external calls that could be causing high gas requirements?

Alternative Approaches: Are there alternative approaches or practices that I should consider for processing the liquidity tax and adding it to Uniswap?

Any suggestions or recommendations would be very valuable. Thank you for your help.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";

contract CustomToken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, ReentrancyGuard, Ownable {
    address public marketingWallet;
    address public uniswapV2RouterAddress;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapV2Router;
    address public uniswapV2Pair;
    uint256 public constant TOTAL_SUPPLY = 450000000000000 * 10**18;
    uint256 public minEthBeforeLiquidity = 0.05 ether;
    uint256 private accumulatedTokenAmount = 0;
    uint256 private accumulatedETHAmount = 0;

    constructor(
        address _marketingWallet,
        address _uniswapV2RouterAddress,
        address initialOwner
    ) ERC20("test", "GRC") Ownable(initialOwner) {
        marketingWallet = _marketingWallet;
        uniswapV2RouterAddress = _uniswapV2RouterAddress;

        uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(uniswapV2RouterAddress);
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapV2Router.WETH());

        _mint(initialOwner, TOTAL_SUPPLY);
    }

    function _update(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual override {
        uint256 marketingFee = (amount * 2) / 100;
        uint256 liquidityFee = (amount * 2) / 100;
        uint256 fees = marketingFee + liquidityFee;
        uint256 sendAmount = amount - fees;

        super._update(from, to, sendAmount);

        if (marketingFee > 0) {
            super._update(from, marketingWallet, marketingFee);
        }

        if (liquidityFee > 0 && from != uniswapV2Pair) {
            accumulatedTokenAmount += liquidityFee;
            uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;
            swapTokensForEth(liquidityFee);
            uint256 receivedEth = address(this).balance - initialBalance;
            accumulatedETHAmount += receivedEth;

            if (accumulatedETHAmount >= minEthBeforeLiquidity) {
                addLiquidity(accumulatedTokenAmount, accumulatedETHAmount);
                accumulatedTokenAmount = 0;
                accumulatedETHAmount = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();

        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0,
            0,
            owner(),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
}
```